# xml foreach function query

Tags: php, xml, xml-parsing

I have not been able to do two days , xml file codes are below  .

```
<?php 

        $tcmb = simplexml_load_file('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml'); 
        $euro = $tcmb->Currency[3]->BanknoteSelling; 
        $dolar = $tcmb->Currency[0]->BanknoteSelling; 

        $xml_data = simplexml_load_file('/public_html/xml/feed_4.xml'); 
        $degisim = new SimpleXMLElement('<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?><DATA></DATA>'); 

        foreach ($xml_data->RECORD as $fiyat) {

            $fiyat = $xml_data->RECORD->FIYAT; 
            $kur = $xml_data->RECORD->DOVIZ_BIRIMI; 
            $track = $degisim->addChild('RECORD'); 

            if ($kur == "USD") $fiyat = round (($xml_data->RECORD->FIYAT * (string)$dolar),2) ; 
            else if ($kur == "EUR") $fiyat = round (($xml_data->RECORD->FIYAT * (string)$euro),2); 
            else $fiyat = $xml_data->RECORD->FIYAT; 
            $track->addChild('STOK_KODU', $xml_data->RECORD->STOK_KODU);
            $track->addChild('newprice', $fiyat); 
            } 
        Header('Content-type: text/xml'); 
        print($degisim->asXML()); 
     ?>
```

Local XML file like as

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<DATA>
 <RECORD>
  <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
  <DOVIZ_BIRIMI>EUR</DOVIZ_BIRIMI>
  <FIYAT>26,5</FIYAT>
 </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
  <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT002</STOK_KODU>
  <DOVIZ_BIRIMI>USD</DOVIZ_BIRIMI>
  <FIYAT>23,805</FIYAT>
 </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
  <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT003</STOK_KODU>
  <DOVIZ_BIRIMI>TL</DOVIZ_BIRIMI>
  <FIYAT>28</FIYAT>
 </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
  <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT004</STOK_KODU>
  <DOVIZ_BIRIMI>TL</DOVIZ_BIRIMI>
  <FIYAT>9,25</FIYAT>
 </RECORD>
 <RECORD>
  <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT005</STOK_KODU>
  <DOVIZ_BIRIMI>TL</DOVIZ_BIRIMI>
  <FIYAT>9,25</FIYAT>
 </RECORD>
</DATA>
```

but when run displaying like this Brings the top product

```
 <DATA>
    <RECORD>
    <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
    <newprice>101.8</newprice>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
    <newprice>101.8</newprice>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
    <newprice>101.8</newprice>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
    <newprice>101.8</newprice>
    </RECORD>
    <RECORD>
    <STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
    <newprice>101.8</newprice>
    </RECORD>
    </DATA>
```

i want to display like this

```
<DATA>
<RECORD>
<STOK_KODU>PRODUCT001</STOK_KODU>
<newprice>101.8</newprice>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<STOK_KODU>PRODUCT002</STOK_KODU>
<newprice>93.2</newprice>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<STOK_KODU>PRODUCT003</STOK_KODU>
<newprice>28</newprice>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<STOK_KODU>PRODUCT004</STOK_KODU>
<newprice>9.25</newprice>
</RECORD>
<RECORD>
<STOK_KODU>PRODUCT005</STOK_KODU>
<newprice>9.25</newprice>
</RECORD>
</DATA>
```

Where am i doing wrong?
I changed a lot of code but I still can not

Comment: Is this right `else if` or typo ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside your `foreach` loop, you are using `$xml_data->RECORD->...` instead of the value of the current element. Thus, you are repeatedly accessing the *first* `RECORD` element in your document.

The loop should probably be written as:

```
foreach ($xml_data->RECORD as $record) {
    $fiyat = floatval(str_replace(',', '.', $record->FIYAT));

    $factor = 1;
    $kur = $record->DOVIZ_BIRIMI;
    if ($kur == "USD") {
        $factor = $dolar;
    }
    else if ($kur == "EUR") {
        $factor = $euro;
    }

    $track = $degisim->addChild('RECORD');
    $track->addChild('STOK_KODU', $record->STOK_KODU);
    $track->addChild('newprice', round($fiyat * $factor, 2));
}
```

I'd also suggest this function to make the exchange rate retrieval more reliable. With your array index approach, you'll get bogus results if the order of the currencies changes.

```
function get_banknote_selling($xml, $currency) {
    return floatval($xml->xpath(sprintf('//Tarih_Date/Currency[@Kod="%s"]',
        $currency))[0]->BanknoteSelling);
}

$tcmb = simplexml_load_file('http://www.tcmb.gov.tr/kurlar/today.xml');
$euro = get_banknote_selling($tcmb, "EUR");
$dolar = get_banknote_selling($tcmb, "USD");
```